# google map store directions for end users

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-maps, magento

I am trying to create a google maps window where the user is asked to use current location and if yes, it inputs there location (marker a) to give them directions to a set location (marker b). If no, an input box will appear for them to type their address and then map the directions.

I currently have the embedded google map using origin=current+location, but it seems inaccurate at times. For example, I just did it a few minutes ago at work and it said my current location was my house.

I'm extremely new to coding so please have mercy on me. I'm entering all of this code into a cms page via Magento admin panel. Anyone willing to help me out, I'd highly appreciate it.

```
<center>
<div style="width:800px;max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:563px;color:red;"><div id="display-google-map" style="height:100%; width:100%;max-width:100%;">
<iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=current+location&destination=630+Royal+Street,+New+Orleans,+LA,+United+States&key=[API_KEY]&zoom=16"></iframe>
</div>
<style>#display-google-map .map-generator{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background: none;</style>
</div>
</center>
```

Here is a live link with my coding: https://uat.rauantiques.com/directions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IP based geolocation shouldn't be really precise. I tried your example and figured out that my location is not correct as well (about 500 meters shifted).